# Symfony Propel Query: setting a non-null value with "false" sets it to "null"

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I have the following code:

`$stmt->setFlag($this->form->getValue("flag")); // $this->form->getValue("flag") = "false"`

Which in my autogenerated Propel class calls the following code:

```
1     public function setFlag($v)
2 {
3     if ($v !== null) {
4         if (is_string($v)) {
5             $v = in_array(strtolower($v), array('false', 'off', '-', 'no', 'n', '0', '')) ? false : true;
6         } else {
7             $v = (boolean) $v;
8         }
9     }
10    if ($this->flag !== $v) {
11        $this->flag = $v;
12        $this->modifiedColumns[] = TableNamePeer::FLAG;
13    }
14    return $this;
15 }
```

My schema entry for the flag is as follows:

`ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN flag BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false;`

My XML entry is as follows:

```
<table name="tablename" phpName="TableName">
    ...
    <column name="flag" phpName="Flag" type="BOOLEAN" required="true" defaultValue="false"/>
    ...
</table>
```

I have verified with XDebug that my form submits the variable using `POST` with the value `false` (and definitely not `null`).

**However, the setFlag function receives the variable as `null`.** The function skips over the `if` branch at line 3 of the `setFlag` function and then sets the `flag` to `null` at line 11 and 12. This yields an error when commiting to the database because the field CANNOT be null.

What is going on here?

**EDIT**:

Interestingly, if I pass my `setFlag` function an actual `false` value, i.e. `$stmt->setFlag(false)`, then `setFlag` receives the correct value the database commit works. What?

**EDIT 2:**

It turns out that the Bootstrap switch I was using is using the `on` value for when the switch/checkbox is clicked, and `null` otherwise, so it was indeed passing `null` to the function and I must have made an error somewhere.

Now the question is whether it would be possible to have the switch pass `false` instead of `null` when it is not clicked, or whether I have to put in a special check for that flag only. Suggestions for either approach would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no good solution that I liked, so I ended up solving my problem as such:

`$stmt->setFlag((bool) $this->form->getValue("flag"));`

The cast is (for my purposes) guaranteed to either yield `true` or `false`, which sufficed.

If anyone has a better idea, I am open to suggestions.